# CPU reached to 700% while reading http stream

Tags: java, servlets

I am using Pushlet for heartbeat , the CPU reaching 700% while the request.
I dump the thread info using jstack.(not using option [-l] for the service running with jdk1.5), all thread with high cpu are blocked in doPost while reading http stream.
one of the thread's stack info as follows:

```
Thread 30777: (state = IN_JAVA)
 - sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder$CharsetSD.readBytes() @bci=23, line=401 (Compiled frame ;information may be imprecise)
 - sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder$CharsetSD.implRead(char[], int, int) @bci=112, line=453 (Compiled frame)
 - sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(char[], int, int) @bci=180, line=183 (Compiled frame)
 - sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read0() @bci=34, line=132 (Compiled frame)
 - nl.justobjects.pushlet.servlet.Pushlet.doPost(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) @bci=15, line=117 (Interpreted frame)
 - javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) @bci=139, line=710 (Interpreted frame)
 - javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(javax.servlet.ServletRequest, javax.servlet.ServletResponse) @bci=30, line=803 (Interpreted frame)
```

Please help to check why it cost so much CPU time while reading stream, in which way can i check this problem.

code for Pushlet.java

```
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Event event = null;
        try {
            // Create Event by parsing XML from input stream.
[line 117]  event = EventParser.parse(new InputStreamReader(request.getInputStream()));
            // Always must have an event type
            if (event.getEventType() == null) {
                Log.warn("Pushlet.doPost(): bad request, no event specified");
                response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST, "No eventType specified");
                return;
            }
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            // Error creating event
            Log.warn("Pushlet:  Error creating event in doPost(): ", t);
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
            return;
        }
        // Handle parsed request
        doRequest(event, request, response);
    }
```

Comment: Can you show your codes ?

Comment: I am using Pushlet 2.0.4, all codes provided by Pushlet project. I can give the code of nl.justobjects.pushlet.servlet.Pushlet

Comment: Which is line 117? And are you sure that stack trace is complete?

Comment: Line 117: event = EventParser.parse(new InputStreamReader(request.getInputStream())); I was confused on the stack trace too. I take the head 7 line here, I think the last of them was unnecessary.

Comment: So I take it this is 700% of an octa-core CPU or a quad-core with hyper-threading? In other words, 7/8 of available computing power?

Comment: yeah, it takes 7 core of a octa-core CPU

Comment: So EventParser.parse(), whatever it is, is taking 7/8 of your processors. What makes you think that Servlets have anything to do with it?